# Android java Queue + Iterator - anyway to get the previous item?

Tags: android, queue

I am using an iterator on a queue, upon iteration, and test the item ( if ..) I get :
sensorEventp1  ( current element )
anyway to get also the previous element  ?

I tried to use a counter (i) , but the Queue sensorQueue doesn't accept get(int) ...
thanks for advices ...

```
    public Vector3 interpolate(Queue<CapturedSensorEvent> sensorQueue, Long interpolationTime, Integer points) {
    Iterator<CapturedSensorEvent> sensorEventsIterator = sensorQueue.iterator();
    Integer i = -1;
    sensorEventsLoop:
    while (sensorEventsIterator.hasNext()) {
        i++;
        CapturedSensorEvent sensorEventp1 = sensorEventsIterator.next();
        if (sensorEventp1.timestamp > interpolationTime) {
            if (points == 2) {
                CapturedSensorEvent sensorEventm1 = sensorQueue.get(i-1);
            }
            break sensorEventsLoop;
        }
    }
    return Vector3.Zero();  // test only
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CapturedSensorEvent previous = null;
while (sensorEventsIterator.hasNext()) {
    i++;
    CapturedSensorEvent sensorEventp1 = sensorEventsIterator.next();
    if (sensorEventp1.timestamp > interpolationTime) {
        if (points == 2) {
            CapturedSensorEvent sensorEventm1 = previous;
        }
        break sensorEventsLoop;
    }
    previous = sensorEventp1;
}
return Vector3.Zero();
```